# submit button in leaflet popup doesn't trigger observeEvent in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I need a workaround for this problem.
I have a submit button inside a popup. When I click on the marker, the input$map_marker_click$id now contains the id of the marker clicked.

There is a submit button in the popup. When the submit button is clicked I want to save the input$map_marker_click$id to a variable. Using oberserveEvent or eventReactive both are not working for me.

Here is the code save it as app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

df <- data.frame("id" = c("1", "2"),
                 "lng" = c(-93.65, -93.655),
                 "lat" = c(42.0285, 42.03),
                 "Text" = c("Department of Statistics", "something else"))


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  textOutput("locationid1"),
  textOutput("locationid2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    df %>% leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
      setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 15) %>%
      addMarkers(layerId = ~id, popup = ~paste("<b>", Text, "</b></br>
                                               <button id='selectlocation' type='button' class='btn btn-default action-button'>Select Location</button>"))
  })


  id1 <- reactive({
     validate(
       need(!is.null(input$map_marker_click), "Please select a location from the map above")
     )
    input$map_marker_click$id
  })

  id2 <- eventReactive(input$selectlocation, {
    input$map_marker_click$id
  })


  output$locationid1 <- renderText({paste("Location Selected using marker click:", id1())})
  output$locationid2 <- renderText({paste("Location Selected using popup select button click:", id2())})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: As a side note, you are creating buttons that have the same id, id's should be unique for HTML elements so maybe you can add the marker number to the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue might be that Shiny does not know you are adding buttons and so there are no bindings.

A dirty trick could be to add an `onclick` function to the buttons that tells Shiny it has been clicked:

For ex:

```
<button onclick='Shiny.onInputChange(\"button_click\",  Math.random())' id='selectlocation' type='button' class='btn btn-default action-button'>Select Location</button>
```

This JS function will send the random number to Shiny, and you can access it in `server.R` using `input$button_click`.

You can then use `input$button_click` in your `eventReactive`

The proper way to do this is probably to use `Shiny.unbindAll()` and `Shiny.bindAll()` [see here](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#dynamic-ui) at the bottom, but I'm not sure how to do that here.

Comment: Thanks. This works. I believe the bindAll and unbindAll methods are used when you are adding the elements using javascript. Here I'm adding directly as a string