# Interactive maps using leaflet in R

Tags: r

I rendered a map using leaflet library in R, so can we make it interactive using R (which identifies a location on click on the map like google maps)

Comment: Does the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986212/area-select-event-for-r-leaflet-in-shiny) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32897559/submit-button-in-leaflet-popup-doesnt-trigger-observeevent-in-shiny) help? It seems you need leaflet + shiny...

Comment: This is not possible with leaflet.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is not possible.  Can you show an example of the interactivity you would like to achieve?

Comment: Can i get the address information on clicking at particular location on leaflet (like in google maps) using R
It is just when you click a particular location on map google maps will display the address and information of the location in the side bar..Can we do that same kind of interaction using leaflet in R.